# How i remove the end

Tags: notepad++, notepad

For the example :

```
 hezekwawed@21cn.com:74314739 | 47
    inferno904011@21cn.com:904011 | 76
    quorkscom@web.de:niko1986 | 6
    fenhanghsvccu@21cn.com:49878442 | 90
```

I want to remove only the `| 47` , and remain the mail and password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy the from 2 sides](https://superuser.com/questions/1253681/how-to-copy-the-from-2-sides)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a literal duplicate of an already closed question. it contains no significant improvements over the prior version.

Answer (score 2):

#### I want to remove only the | 47 , and remain the mail and password

I'm going to assume you want to remove all the strings after the passwords that start with `|`.

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `\| .*`
- Set "Replace with" to an empty string
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Before:

```
hezekwawed@21cn.com:74314739 | 47
    inferno904011@21cn.com:904011 | 76
    quorkscom@web.de:niko1986 | 6
    fenhanghsvccu@21cn.com:49878442 | 90
```

After:

```
hezekwawed@21cn.com:74314739 
    inferno904011@21cn.com:904011 
    quorkscom@web.de:niko1986 
    fenhanghsvccu@21cn.com:49878442
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)